# pam_tacplus.so and sshd: skip user validation?

Tags: pam, sshd

I'm trying to implement tacacs authentication on a freebsd box as a client.  The box is actually a network appliance that SHOULD have this config built into its cli/ui but doesn't.  Since it's built on freebsd, it has the [pam_tacplus.so](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pam_tacplus&sektion=8) library built in.

My problem is that I wish to authenticate to our tacacs server, but I don't wish to configure local accounts on the appliance.  Here's the pam.conf file:

```
su      auth        sufficient  pam_rootok.so
su      auth        sufficient  pam_unix.so

login   auth            required        pam_unix.so
login   account         required        pam_unix.so
login   password        required        pam_permit.so
login   session         required        pam_permit.so

ftpd    auth            required        pam_unix.so

sshd    auth            sufficient      pam_tacplus.so  template_user=testuser      
sshd    auth            required        pam_unix.so
sshd    account         required        pam_unix.so
sshd    password        required        pam_permit.so
sshd    session         required        pam_permit.so

telnetd auth            required        pam_unix.so

passwd  password        required        pam_unix.so     no_warn try_first_pass nullok

other   auth            required        pam_unix.so
```

The tacacs server's ip address is stored in /etc/tacplus.conf and since I see failures in the tacacs server's log, I believe communication is successful.  Additionally, I can establish TCP session to server on port 49.

When I try to log in via ssh as jimbob, here's what I see in the /var/log/auth.log:

```
<auth.info> Lab-2 sshd[4952]: Invalid user jimbob from 10.0.0.1
<auth.info> Lab-2 sshd[4952]: input_userauth_request: invalid user jimbob
<auth.info> Lab-2 sshd[4952]: Failed none for invalid user jimbob from 10.0.0.1 port 52069 ssh2
<auth.info> Lab-2 sshd[4952]: Failed publickey for invalid user jimbob from 10.0.0.1 port 52069 ssh2
<auth.info> Lab-2 sshd[4952]: Postponed keyboard-interactive for invalid user jimbob from 10.0.0.1 port 52069 ssh2
<auth.info> Lab-2 sshd[4952]: Postponed keyboard-interactive/pam for invalid user jimbob from 10.0.0.1 port 52069 ssh2
<auth.err> Lab-2 sshd[4953]: error: ssh_msg_send: write
```

After searching around, [this](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/openssh/dev/49585) seems to apply.  This, however, talks about NSS, which is controlled by nsswitch.conf, which doesn't exist on this system.  There doesn't appear to be a tacacs plugin for NSS; I'm not sure that it would matter, in my case, if there were.

So, is there a way to skip checking the local passwd file for a user before getting to the pam_tacplus.so library?  I'm guessing that if there were, the template_user= option would kick in and try to use 'testuser,' which DOES exist as a localuser:

```
pw user show testuser
testuser:*:1003:1003::0:0:User &:/home/testuser:/usr/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this easily, as I have.
You are right, you should use the nsswitch.conf file. However you will have to install a third party program , libnss-ato, which stands for All-To-One. It will validate non-local users against a a configured tacacs+ server, then behave exactly as you wished.

You can get that package and its details here:
https://github.com/donapieppo/libnss-ato

Comment: I had the same problem and able to fix with this